# conditional if statements within while loops

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I am semi-new to matlab, and have written a while loop that will generate a value from a data set by scanning through the data set until the data line is above a threshold value. here is a part of the code:

```
 c = 1;
      while min(obj_cont1(c:c+Grip_sample_length,n)) < Grasp_Threshold
      c = c + 1; 
      end

      contact_time_index(n,1) = c;
```

the problem is, this part of the code is within a larger for loop, and the code is meant to find the first value that a data portion is above this "grasp_threshold" (a value that I seimply set manually). My question is: if no value ever meets this criteria, is there a way to have the code enter a value (such as a zero, or null) to indicate that it ran through, didn't find a result, and so it went to the next data set? right now if the code doesn't find a result, it will run through all the trials in the for loop, but will give me an error at the end.

I hope this is clear. My matlab jargon needs some development, just as my coding skills do

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where are you storing any values in the loop?  Also could you explain the overall problem more?  There are some better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that might help you out significantly.

Let's say I run the following commands:

```
x = [];
for i = 1:10
   x(i) = i^2;
end
```

Now if I want to get all elements that have a log greater than 5 or really evaluate true to any function I can do so like this

```
elementsGreaterThan5 = x(log(x) > 5)
```

I would suggest using this approach to find the element you need

See logical indexing [Matrix Indexing in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using that `max` returns the first maximal element (that is the first 1 in a 0-1 array), your code is equivalent to this:

```
[is_above, first_idx_above_tsh] = max(obj_cont1(:,n) >= Grasp_Threshold); 
contact_time_index(n,1) = max(first_idx_above_tsh - Grip_sample_length, 1);
```

where `is_above` will tell you if there is any element above the threshold.

If you have an outer for-loop and `Grasp_Threshold` and `Grip_sample_length` is fixed, you don't even need to put this calculation into that for loop:

```
[is_above, first_idx_above_tsh] = max(obj_cont1 >= Grasp_Threshold); 
contact_time_index(:,1) = max(first_idx_above_tsh - Grip_sample_length, 1);
```

Here both `is_above` and `first_idx_above_tsh` are vectors.